# How to server-render redux app with async requests?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to build server-rendered redux app with API request required to render route handler React components.

I'm passing request-making function in my actions and custom middleware fires requests and dispatches their results. For client it works just fine, but I'm struggling tow things at server-rendering:

1. I need to know, which API requests are necessary for route rendering and don't want to duplicate that knowledge in both client and server-renderer code.
2. On server I need to know then my API requests ended so I could render html to string and throw it to client.

Any ideas/links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing the same, basically using a function to get all the needed information from API calls, by specifying in your components which actions should run to fetch information.

I don't want to spend much time explaining that here, because there is an excellent tutorial of how to achieve this [here](https://medium.com/@bananaoomarang/handcrafting-an-isomorphic-redux-application-with-love-40ada4468af4) (And it works perfect)

Cheers.

Comment: Tutorial is somewhat 'first steps', but ideas are really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: [Link only answers are discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/203384). The article is very helpful, but your answer becomes useless if the linked resource goes down. Please write a summary for it that contains the relevant information.